# Is there a way to access XML elements inside CDATA with Xpath?

Tags: xml, xpath

In the following example I want to access specifications:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items><item>
<product_code><![CDATA[ASDF123]]></product_code>
<product_name><![CDATA[Some name]]></product_name>
<specifications>
<![CDATA[<Tech>Some tech</Tech>]]>
<![CDATA[<Neto weight>166 kg</Neto weight>]]>
</specifications>
</item></items>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no XML elements inside CDATA.

CDATA is explicitly a way of saying "Treat characters which would normally have special meaning in XML as plain text".

If that wasn't the case, then the XML parser would throw an error as `<Neto weight>166 kg</Neto weight>` is invalid XML.

So: No.

(The real problem here appears to be that that XML is poorly designed and doesn't have a means to express the specifics of the specifications element)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I tought. Just wanted a second opinion.